# Convert Sub Query Into LEFT Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have BaseProducts, Images and ProductsImages(many to many) tables. I have this query,

```
SELECT BaseProducts.*, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Images.[Path] 
        FROM   Images AS Images 
               INNER JOIN ProductsImages AS ProductsImages 
                       ON Images.Id = ProductsImages.ImageId 
        WHERE  ProductsImages.BaseProductId = BaseProducts.Id 
        ORDER  BY [ProductsImages].[Order]) AS ImagePath 
FROM   CTEPage AS BaseProducts
```

This works but it looks clumsy to me. Can I convert this into JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to a `join`.  But that would be uglier.  In SQL Server, it is easier to express this using `apply`:

```
SELECT BaseProducts.*
       i.ImagePath, AS ImagePath
FROM CTEPage BaseProducts OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 Images.[Path] as ImagePath
      FROM Images i INNER JOIN
           ProductsImages pi
           ON i.Id = pi.ImageId
      WHERE pi.BaseProductId = BaseProducts.Id
      ORDER BY [ProductsImages].[Order]
     ) i;
```

Doing this as a `join` would require using `row_number()` to extract the "first" image path.

Comment: It would need to be an outer apply to maintain the same semantics if no matching value exists.

Comment: @MartinSmith or GordonLinoff, which one will be better in terms of performance?

Comment: @user960567 . . . The difference between `cross apply` and `outer apply` is not going to have a big impact on performance.

Comment: No I am asking between sub-query and apply

Comment: @user960567 . . . You would need to try on your own data.  The apply often performs well in this context.